# Get all positive integral solutions for a linear equation

Tags: python, sympy

A game I played has a riddle that involves solving the following equation:

```
x*411 + y*295 + z*161 = 3200
```

Not wanting to think I just slapped it into `sympy`, which I haven’t really used up to that point:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z', integer=True, positive=True)
>>> solve(x*411 + y*295 + z*161 - 3200, [x, y, z])
[{x: -295*y/411 - 161*z/411 + 3200/411}]
```

Hmm, this only gave me a dependent solution, but I want all possible solutions in the domain I constrained the variables to, e.g. (assuming there are no other solutions) `[{x: 4, y: 2, z:6}]` or `[(4, 2, 6)]`

Of course I could now manually substitute two variables in a nested loop, or solve it by hand (as I did to get the solution above), but I want to know how to get sympy (or another library) to do it for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to solve? It is impossible to solve 3 unknown variables from only one equation.

Comment: This is a linear Diophantine equation, so the module [diophantine](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html) should be used. It returns `(t_0, 2627*t_0 + 161*t_1 - 19200, -4816*t_0 - 295*t_1 + 35200)` but there is no built-in way to enforce positivity there....   @HendriTobing The unknowns are positive integers, so there are finitely many solutions. The OP wants all of those solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SymPy can [solve Diophantine equations](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html) but doesn't have a built-in way to generate positive solutions.  With [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) one can do that easily: here is four-line code that generates all **nonnegative integer solutions** of your equation.

```
p = MixedIntegerLinearProgram()
w = p.new_variable(integer=True, nonnegative=True)
p.add_constraint(411*w[0] + 295*w[1] + 161*w[2] == 3200)
p.polyhedron().integral_points()
```

The output is `((4, 2, 6),)`

Behind the scenes, `integral_points` will most likely just run a multiple loop; although when that doesn't seem to work it tries to use Smith normal form.

I know you wanted positive solutions, but (a) it's easy to exclude any zero-containing tuples from the answer; (b) it's also easy to replace x by x-1, etc, prior to solving; (c) sticking to "nonnegative" makes it easy to create a polyhedron using [Mixed Integer Linear Programming module](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/numerical/sage/numerical/mip.html)
 as above.

According to documentation one can also build a [Polyhedron object](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/base.html) directly from a system of inequalities ("Hrep"). This would allow one to explicitly say x >= 1, etc, but I haven't succeeded at this route.

#### With SymPy

The output of SymPy's Diophantine module is a parametric solution, like

```
(t_0, 2627*t_0 + 161*t_1 - 19200, -4816*t_0 - 295*t_1 + 35200)
```

in your example. This can be used in a loop to generate solutions in a pretty efficient way. The sticky point is finding bounds for parameters t_0 and t_1. Since this is just an illustration,  I looked at the last expression above and plugged the limits 35200/4816 and 35200/295 directly in the loops below.

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
[s] = diophantine(x*411 + y*295 + z*161 - 3200)
print(s)
t_0, t_1 = s[2].free_symbols
for t0 in range(int(35200/4816)+1):
    for t1 in range(int(35200/295)+1):
        sol = [expr.subs({t_0: t0, t_1: t1}) for expr in s]
        if min(sol) > 0:
            print(sol)
```

The output is `[4, 2, 6]`.