# array of Weighted random numbers with constant sum

Tags: python, random, statistics

Is there any well-known algorithm which can generate an array of weighted random numbers having the same constant sum?

This problem can be stated in another way: Say, I have a total value of 20. Which should be distributed into 3 parts each of them has a weight of 2,4,3 respectively.
So, I need 3 random numbers which will have a sum of 20 but the distribution will follow the weight.

I have tried:

```
Range=20
W=[2,4,3]
Prob=[i/float(sum(W)) for i in W]
Weighted_array=np.random.multinomial(Range, Prob)
```

Is there any better option?

Comment: I have tried with random.multinomial() in python.

Comment: Please give more detail. What kind of numbers do you mean--only positive integers, or are float numbers allowed? What do you mean by "the distribution will follow the weight"? What kind of probability distribution do you want for the results--some kind of uniform distribution over all possibilities, you don't care, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for unclarity. I need to generate integers. For that example the weighted_array can be: [4,10,6],[3,12,5] etc. "the distribution will follow the weight" means the resultant array elements will be weighted according to the W array elements. Hope that makes clear.

Comment: But you have 20 potential numbers sampled and only three weights. Suppose I use your code as a black box, sample 1mln samples and just put them in histogram from 1 (or zero? a bit unclear) to 20. How those three weight will manifest themselves?

Answer (score 0):

**Symbolic:**

This is a linear Diophantine equation of `n=3` variables. To solve it analytically in python you can use `sympy`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013884/get-all-positive-integral-solutions-for-a-linear-equation):

```
from random import randint
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diop_linear
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

# Our original equation is 2 * x + 4 * y + 3 * z = 20
# Re-arrange to 2 * x + 4 * y + 3 * z - 20 = 0, and input the left side to sympy
general_solution = diop_linear(2 * x + 4 * y + 3 * z - 20)

def get_random_valid_triple():
    t0,t1 = general_solution[2].free_symbols
    # You can pick whatever bounds you want here
    a = randint(-100, 100)
    b = randint(-100, 100)
    solution = [s.subs({t0: a, t1:b}) for s in general_solution]
    print(solution)
# Get a random solution
get_random_valid_triple()
```

---

**Brute Force:**

Alternately, at least for small `n` and tight bounds on each variable, you can just precompute all possible solutions and use `random.choice` to choose one each time. For example, we restrict all of the variables to be positive, then they're forced to be in `[0,  20 / coefficient]`, and there are only 14 solutions. We can generate these in python as follows:

```
import random
import itertools
n = 20
coefficients = [2, 4, 3]
valid_solutions = []
ranges = [range(0, n // k + 1) for k in coefficients]
for value in itertools.product(*ranges):
    if sum(value[j] * i for j, i in enumerate(coefficients)) == n:
        valid_solutions.append(value)

print("All solutions:")
print("\n".join(str(i) for i in valid_solutions))
print("Random solution:")
print(random.choice(valid_solutions))
```

This yields:

```
All solutions:
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 5, 0)
(1, 0, 6)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 4)
(2, 4, 0)
(3, 2, 2)
(4, 0, 4)
(4, 3, 0)
(5, 1, 2)
(6, 2, 0)
(7, 0, 2)
(8, 1, 0)
(10, 0, 0)
Random solution:
(10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But the problem is I need a general solution for n variables. Because my array W can have 100 or more elements. So, I think diophantine will not be the efficient one.